Rails 7 devise lockable + paranoid not displaying lock message
In my Rails 7 Ruby 3.2.1 app, I'm using Devise and devise-security gems with the paranoid settings enabled (config.paranoid = true). Since a pentest report arrived on my table, I now need to lock a user after 5 attempts. When config.paranoid = true is set, the account is locked after 5 attempts:
# rails console
[10] pry(main)> User.last.access_locked?
=> true

However, it still shows Invalid Email or password. and both the email and password fields are active, instead of Your account is locked. I need to display the same message everywhere else, so I really need config.paranoid = true.
When I set config.paranoid = false everything will work as expected for the login endpoint (it will show the Your account is locked) but I'll loose the generic messages for everything else. Is there some settings which I missed to make it happen or it's not possible?
Below is my devise.rb:
Devise.setup do |config|
  # some other settings
  config.paranoid = true
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
  config.unlock_keys = [:email]
  config.unlock_strategy = :time
  config.maximum_attempts = 5
  config.unlock_in = 30.minutes
  config.last_attempt_warning = false

My user.rb model:
class User < ApplicationRecord # rubocop:disable Metrics/ClassLength
  devise \
    :confirmable,
    :database_authenticatable,
    :invitable,
    :lockable,
    :omniauthable,
    :recoverable,
    :registerable,
    :timeoutable,
    :trackable,
    :secure_validatable,
    :password_expirable,
    :password_archivable


You are at cross purposes here - paranoid is about denying the attacker feedback about whether or not they found a resource. Indicating an account is locked reveals the existence of the account.

@dbugger I know that but don't have any other option to let user know that his account has been locked.

A) don’t let them know. B) send them an email

One of the options that I see is to do the following:

Send email to a user when they get locked
[Optionally] Instead of Invalid email or password. message show Invalid email or password, or account is locked.

